# Scala - function which takes a type composition of 2 traits

Tags: scala, syntax, traits

I want my function to receive a type which implements 2 traits.

Is it possible to create an "adhoc" trait type like that?

For instance:

```
trait t1 {
... //stuff....
}

trait t2 {
... // more stuff....
}

class MyClass {
   def functionMix(input : t1&&t2 type) {
       .... the input implements t1 and t2 trait
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar

def doStuff(f: Foo with Bar) = ???
```